# Where do I find the PDF version of Sivatatwaviveka?

Tags: scripture

Where do I find the PDF version of Sivatatwaviveka? I have searched all possible websites and still searching.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have only English Translation of  [Sri Shiva Tattva Viveka](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507002544if_/https://doc-14-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/u9n7o5544quo1574hf0pubuph6v3l2vj/1620347100000/02058467015715614041/*/1xhJQXYy3Tn_zOFBZgpNlafZjwqxeAZSxzej3Ws6Mhq2SWlGvZPjspVj8b_io4aIswYpGMZM6oJxuXf5l?e=download)  with the commentary of Sri Appayya Dikshitar in pdf format.

Hope it helps.

|| Om Tat Sat ||

Comment: Then kindly help me read it and forward the same to other devotees please.

Comment: I have already given the link na just press in the blue section and it will get downloaded automatically and for for forwarding it those who want can download it from here only snd you can also forward it in other sites, etc. Click the blue colour "Sri Shiva Tattva Viveka" part. N U r welcome. .. ।। ॐ नमः शिवाय: ।।

Comment: I have given 2 emojis for ease. Hope it helps. ..